# How do you actually *use* firebase-server for testing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/urish/firebase-server#usage-example yet it seems to be missing a MCVE.

This is the one I tried to create as `foo.js`:

```
Firebase = require('firebase');

client = new Firebase('http://localhost.firebaseio.test:5000');
client.on('value', function(thing) {
    console.log('Stuff: ', thing.val());
});
```

Yet when I run it with `node foo.js` I just get

```
TypeError: Firebase is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/wayne/programming/foo.js:3:10)
```

Obviously that's not what I'm looking for. So I thought, maybe it's referring to an out-of-date version of Firebase. So let's just try replacing this with `firebase-admin`:

```
firebase = require('firebase-admin');

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: 'http://localhost.firebaseio.test:5000',
});

db = firebase.database().ref()
db.once('value')
    .then(function(thing) {
        console.log('Stuff: ', thing.val());
    });
```

(I have no clue if that's how it's supposed to look: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/blob/master/database/index.js was the simplest example I could find)

But this just hangs at the prompt like it's planning to do something but never does.

I've started my firebase server with `node_modules/.bin/firebase-server -p 5000 -e`, and I can see it connect with some of the more complicated code we have in our codebase, but it's *way* more than an MCVE, which is what I'm just trying to make. I want to be able to connect to my firebase server and see that I can read and write to things.

How does one even use `firebase-server` to test? Is there and MCVE that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

What that example of `firebase-server` usage example might be missing is, that `127.0.0.1 localhost.firebaseio.test` needs to be added into `/etc/hosts`, else it might not resolve. as one can see from `firebase-server -h`, one has to pass the config & data JSON files as options. would suggest to use "Realtime Database" & "Cloud Functions", instead of trying to run a custom WS server - because for testing, one would have to supply the JSON files expected - and the front-end JavaScript library might most likely fail to authenticate, hence one needs credentials.

The documentations says, that `firebase-server` is a *Firebase Web Socket Protocol Server* (which sounds standalone and might implement [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)); it's something different than `firebase serve` (it is unclear to me which one you mean, hence the examples were mixed up - which might be the source of confusion)... for `Google Firebase` one can get a test server and cloud functions emulator with `npm install -g firebase-tools`; and when running the local test server with the `--debug` option, it should reveal where it may get stuck:

```
firebase serve --debug
```

to be executed from within the project's directory.

eg. it may be lacking access permission to globally installed modules' directories:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/logs
sudo chown -R ....
```

installing the `@google-cloud/functions-emulator` on the project level also might circumvent that.

and you'd also require a `firebase.json` there, which controls the deployment.

for example, loading `public/index.html`, which then loads `firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase.js` would be required for checking in front-end JavaScript, if the authentication had succeeded (`firebase setup:web` generates the code) & whether **the user** is authenticated & has permissions to `read/write` on a certain reference path.

```
{
  "database": {
  "rules": "database.rules.json"
},
"hosting": {
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

while `firebase functions:shell` will run that functions emulator, as a Node shell.

the `firebase/index.js` is for nodeJS, and eg. `firebase/package.json` may reference:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.1.10",
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^1.1.4"
    
  }
}
```

`firebase-admin` might require a service-account:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});
```

the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) also explain most of it... and of course `firebase --help`.